# What is the difference between ChildPage.objects.child_of(self) and ParentPage.get_children()?

Tags: wagtail, django-taggit

I think that `ChildPage.objects.child_of(self)` and `ParentPage.get_children()` produce same result because `subpage_types` of **ParentPage** is just one `['ChildPage']`.

But when I try to filter the result of `ParentPage.get_children()` there is an error.

```py
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        child = self.get_children().live().public()               # <- don't works
        child = ChildPage.objects.child_of(self).live().public()  # <- works

        if request.GET.get('tag', None):
            tags = request.GET.get('tag')
            child = child.filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])  # <- error here

        context["child"] = child
        return context
```

#### Traceback (most recent call last):

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'tags' into field. Choices are: alias_of, alias_of_id, aliases, blogindexpage, blogpage, content_type, content_type_id, depth, draft_title, expire_at, expired, first_published_at, formsubmission, go_live_at, group_permissions, has_unpublished_changes, homepage, id, last_published_at, latest_revision_created_at, live, live_revision, live_revision_id, locale, locale_id, locked, locked_at, locked_by, locked_by_id, numchild, owner, owner_id, partnerindexpage, partnerpage, path, redirect, revisions, search_description, seo_title, show_in_menus, sites_rooted_here, slug, title, translation_key, url_path, view_restrictions, workflow_states, workflowpage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `self.get_children()`, the page type of the child pages is not known in advance - a page's children may include multiple different types. Since Django querysets don't (as standard*) support combining data from multiple models, the results are returned as the basic `Page` type, which just contains the core fields common to all pages such as the title and slug. Filtering on `tags` therefore fails, because that field does not exist on the Page model.

With `ChildPage.objects.child_of(self)`, Django knows in advance that the page type is ChildPage - if `self` had any child pages of other types - they would not be included in the results - so it can query directly on the ChildPage table, and consequently all fields of ChildPage (including `tags`) are available for filtering.

* Wagtail does provide a `specific()` method on the queryset to pull in the full data of the pages, but this is implemented as a postprocessing step after the main database query is done, so this still won't allow you to `filter` on fields that aren't part of the base Page model.